# Why do cults thrive?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-religion

The Catholic Church is currently the largest cult in the world and is thriving to the point of having the richest country in the world.

The empirical data to support the Church definition can be researched by reading about the Council of Nicaea (325 CE) The Church suffered a great schism over the definition of the Trinity. The bishops VOTED to create Jesus as a co equal of God and also created the bible. The vote broke the first commandment when they usurped God as first and placed "Christ"ianity 
before God. Notwithstanding belief in God, their religion has that great, ignored flaw.

Why do Catholics follow this cult, it is not recognized by God but is man made.

What part of the human psyche allows cults to exist and thrive?

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.se. Second, the question is not as written something that belongs on this SE. It sounds like your question belongs is psychology, anthropology, sociology. Third, the parts about your question are dubious to the point that you should learn what "cult" means. The catholic church does not meet the popular or sociological definition of cult.

Comment: @virmaior "The catholic church does not meet the popular or sociological definition of cult." -- Hell it doesn't. I agree this question is about psychology and not philosophy; but if the Catholic church is not a cult, then nothing's a cult. They don't commonly get called a cult because they've been around so long; but that should not fool a sharp-eyed philosopher. A cult is "a system of religious veneration and devotion directed toward a particular figure or object." I rest my case. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cult+definition

Comment: Well your case needs to wake back up. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult for a better explanation of what cult means. So they definitely don't mean the sociological definition. And if you look beneath the fold in the same google definition box, you'll see the example is "the cult of st. olaf." To be a cult means to do religion in a particular way -- not merely to be a religion.

Comment: This seems tendentious and anti-Catholic. 'Cult' is a loaded term.

Comment: The last time this question was asked, it did not get an answer as far as I know. The only thing that has changed is that it is now worded in a more inflammatory way.

Comment: Regardless of the definition of "cult", the question is not a philosophical one. *"Why do Catholics follow this cult?"* is for Christianity.SE or CogSci.SE, depending on your angle, and *"What part of the human psyche allows cults to exist and thrive?"* is definitely CogSci.SE. The general question, "Why do cults thrive?", is very interesting to me; I went to school in the first place to answer that very question. But it is unfortunately not on-topic here. :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually there was great unity at the end of the debate. All but two Bishops held to Arius view at the end of the debate. Also they did not hold to Jesus being a seperate God entity but merely being a physical manifestation of the one and only God. Orthodox Christianity has at the very least always been Mono Theistic.

Answer (score 1):

The Catholic Church doesn't meet the ***FBI's*** criteria for cult- that's about it.

When it comes down to it, many people drift towards a feeling of community. It's the same reason gangs thrive- it gives members a sense of belonging and importance. And in metaphysics, it gives ANSWERS to things that other areas of society doesn't have answers to (or at least the answers they WANT).

In the end, I believe people follow another man (a priest, pastor, etc.) for verification of existing beliefs. Everyone seems to be in agreement that you don't have to be in a church to talk to God.. but we still go. We still pay. And we still ask questions to MEN. And if a MAN wearing a specific outfit gives you an answer- you feel it has credence over what YOU can gather out of a book yourself.

Comment: So like Neil Degrasse Tyson for some?

Comment: @virmaior Excellent.  I had to google NDT, but as soon as I saw the images I had a wry smile.  The recent remake of Cosmos was torture to watch, but there is a bit of NDT in all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Human evolved as tribal people, so being in a tribe is in our instincts.  See Freud's [Group Psychology and the Analysis of the Ego](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Psychology_and_the_Analysis_of_the_Ego).

Cults are obviously rather like tribes.